# Conversion of m4a file names

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, codecs, itunes, m4a

Hi everyone hoping I can find an answer to my music related question.  I switched from PC to Ubuntu and had run iTunes in the past.

I have a lot of music that I have the CDs for but I loaded them into the system one by one.

The problem is that although the files still exist they have been named something useless such as 'AVHB', 'GCDF' or whatever.  I can play the files in Rhythmbox and on my android phone and the correct name comes up but the FILE name is not an accuarte descriptor of the file.

So my question is: How do I create a script with python or whatever to run these files through the CODEC and properly rename the files?  The players have the conversions I just don't seem to be able to jump the gap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `id3ren` which is a ID3Tag file renamer.  The application is in the repositories, so it can be easily installed.  This should work as well with `.m4a` files.

```
sudo apt-get install id3ren
```

To use it, go to the folder where your music is, preferably into an actual folder where you have music that you want renamed.  Then you can rename using a template that is offered by `id3ren`.  Template options are as follows:

```
   -template=TEMPLATE
          Use TEMPLATE as the basis for renaming files.  The default tem‐
          plate used is '[%a]-[%s].mp3'.  Identifiers that can be used in
          the template are:
            %a  - Artist name
            %c  - Comment
            %s  - Song name
            %t  - Album title
            %n  - Track Number
            %y  - Year
            %g  - Genre
```

Using a directory from my system here that I know is named incorrectly we can see the files before running `id3ren` on the files:

```
$ ls -l *.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3851479 Jul 10 20:31 01 - Track 1.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3726796 Jul 10 20:31 02 - Track 2.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5001982 Jul 10 20:31 03 - Track 3.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3111721 Jul 10 20:32 04 - Track 4.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4680892 Jul 10 20:32 05 - Track 5.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4504918 Jul 10 20:32 06 - Track 6.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5135839 Jul 10 20:32 07 - Track 7.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5397715 Jul 10 20:32 08 - Track 8.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3229732 Jul 10 20:32 09 - Track 9.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3760156 Jul 10 20:32 10 - Track 10.mp3
```

Now, running `id3ren` on the folder with the template options for `Track Number - Song Name.mp3` using all `mp3` files `(*.mp3)` in that folder:

```
$ id3ren -template='%n - %s.mp3' *.mp3
01 - Track 1.mp3                       => 01 - Your Song.mp3                   
02 - Track 2.mp3                       => 02 - Daniel.mp3                      
03 - Track 3.mp3                       => 03 - Honky Cat.mp3                   
04 - Track 4.mp3                       => 04 - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3   
05 - Track 5.mp3                       => 05 - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3     
06 - Track 6.mp3                       => 06 - Rocket Man.mp3                  
07 - Track 7.mp3                       => 07 - Benny and the Jets.mp3          
08 - Track 8.mp3                       => 08 - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3
09 - Track 9.mp3                       => 09 - Border Song.mp3                 
10 - Track 10.mp3                      => 10 - Crocodile Rock.mp3              
Processed: 10  Failed: 0  Total: 10
```

As we can see now, the folder has had the files renamed to match the ID3Tag contained in the `.mp3` file itself:

```
$ ls -l *.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3851479 Oct 24 15:39 01 - Your Song.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3726796 Oct 24 15:39 02 - Daniel.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5001982 Oct 24 15:39 03 - Honky Cat.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3111721 Oct 24 15:39 04 - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4680892 Oct 24 15:39 05 - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4504918 Oct 24 15:39 06 - Rocket Man.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5135839 Oct 24 15:39 07 - Benny and the Jets.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5397715 Oct 24 15:39 08 - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3229732 Oct 24 15:39 09 - Border Song.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3760156 Oct 24 15:39 10 - Crocodile Rock.mp3
```

**EDIT:** Also ran with Artist name for batch rename.  This works as long as the Artist tag is correct in the ID3 tag:

*This with [artist] - [track] - [name]*

```
$ id3ren -template='%a - %n - %s.mp3' *.mp3
01 - Your Song.mp3                     => Elton John - 01 - Your Song.mp3      
02 - Daniel.mp3                        => Elton John - 02 - Daniel.mp3         
03 - Honky Cat.mp3                     => Elton John - 03 - Honky Cat.mp3      
04 - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3     => Elton John - 04 - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3
05 - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3       => Elton John - 05 - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3
06 - Rocket Man.mp3                    => Elton John - 06 - Rocket Man.mp3     
07 - Benny and the Jets.mp3            => Elton John - 07 - Benny and the Jets.mp3
08 - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3 => Elton John - 08 - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3
09 - Border Song.mp3                   => Elton John - 09 - Border Song.mp3    
10 - Crocodile Rock.mp3                => Elton John - 10 - Crocodile Rock.mp3 
Processed: 10  Failed: 0  Total: 10
```

*This with [track] - [artist] - [name]*

```
$ id3ren -template='%n - %a - %s.mp3' *.mp3
Elton John - 01 - Your Song.mp3        => 01 - Elton John - Your Song.mp3      
Elton John - 02 - Daniel.mp3           => 02 - Elton John - Daniel.mp3         
Elton John - 03 - Honky Cat.mp3        => 03 - Elton John - Honky Cat.mp3      
Elton John - 04 - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3 => 04 - Elton John - Goodbye Yellow Brick Road.mp3
Elton John - 05 - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3 => 05 - Elton John - Saturday Nights Alright.mp3
Elton John - 06 - Rocket Man.mp3       => 06 - Elton John - Rocket Man.mp3     
Elton John - 07 - Benny and the Jets.mp3 => 07 - Elton John - Benny and the Jets.mp3
Elton John - 08 - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3 => 08 - Elton John - Dont Let the Sun Go Down on Me.mp3
Elton John - 09 - Border Song.mp3      => 09 - Elton John - Border Song.mp3    
Elton John - 10 - Crocodile Rock.mp3   => 10 - Elton John - Crocodile Rock.mp3 
Processed: 10  Failed: 0  Total: 10
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome application [EasyTAG](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG), among other features, provides a GUI that allows bulk renaming of music files from metadata, including .m4a files, by using pattern templates.

[image: Bulk renamer screenshot]

For example, the pattern `%n - %a - %t` would rename files to:

```
[track number] - [artist] - [title].[extension]
```

You can safely compare the effects of different patterns before committing to renaming the files.  More help on this feature is provided with the application and is also available [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/easytag/stable/file-rename.html.en).

You can install EasyTAG from the command line by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```